# UITableViewCell image changes when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a title and an image on each cell. Some cells will have a default image and others will not. When I scroll the table, the image of some rows is not the expected and the image of another row gets displayed instead of the expected one. If I don't use dequeuereuseidentifier everything works fine, but I want to use it because I have lots of cells.

Any suggestion?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

        CGRect titleRect = CGRectMake(60, 6, 200, 24);
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: titleRect];
        title.tag = 1;
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AdelleBasic-Bold" size:15.5];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

        UIImageView *defaultCellImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 42, 42)];
        defaultCellImage.tag = 2;
        [defaultCellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default_Row_Image"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:defaultCellImage];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Movie *movie = [_movies objectAtIndex: row];

    UILabel *titleRowLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    titleRowLabel.text = [movie title];

    UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    if (![movie.imageName isEqualToString:@""])
        [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [movie imageName]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first cells to be used in your table view will be properly loaded. Since there is no cell to dequeue, the `if (cell == nil)` will return `YES` and your cell will have its image set to be the default. Then, if your condition for setting a different image is satisfied later in the method, a different image will be shown. So far, so good.

However, when a reusable cell is dequeued, it already has an image set, which might not be the default. Since `cell == nil` will now return `NO`, this cell will never have its image reset to the default one, even if it is the image that should be shown.