# Cells changing when scrolling in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the answers are doing the trick for me. When I am scrolling down the UITableView and then scroll back up, the cells content changes and it seems like it is another cells contents. How can i fix this issue, if a code sample can be provided that would be great. Here is one answer i tried, makes sense but i do not know how to implement: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799561/uitableviewcell-image-changes-when-scrolling?rq=1)

Here is the code I have

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{


  SearchedCell *cell = (SearchedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];

  if (!cell)
  {
      cell = [[SearchedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
  }


  NSDictionary *dict = [[appDel.jsonDict valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if([dict valueForKey:@"BusinessUrl"] == nil)
  {
    cell.btnMenu.hidden = TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    cell.btnMenu.hidden = FALSE;
  }

  cell.lblRestaurantName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];

  NSString *tmpAddr = [dict valueForKey:kResponseVicinity];
  cell.lblAddress.text = tmpAddr;
  if(appDel.isNearClicked)
  {
      cell.lblDistance.text = @"";
  }
  else
  {
    cell.lblDistance.text = @"";
  }
  cell.lblPhoneNo.text = [dict valueForKey:@"Phone"];

  [cell.btnCall addTarget:self action:@selector(CallClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.btnMap addTarget:self action:@selector(MapClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(MenuClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  cell.btnCall.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.btnMap.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.btnMenu.tag = indexPath.row;

  return cell;

}
```

Comment: What all contents are changing?

Comment: The rating is changing. It shows one value and then when i scroll down and scroll back up it shows a different value.

Comment: Did you update the rating in model?

Comment: are you getting rating value in some array? I guess i have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell class.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like this:-

```
-(NSArray *)SetSelectionArray:(NSArray *)OldArray :(NSUInteger )index
{

 NSMutableArray *TempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableDictionary *modifyDict=[[OldArray objectAtIndex:index] mutableCopy];
 if ([[modifyDict valueForKey:@"selectionState"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
 {
    [modifyDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"selectionState"];
 }
 else
 {
    [modifyDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"selectionState"];
 }

TempArr=[OldArray mutableCopy];
[TempArr replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:modifyDict];
return [TempArr copy];
```

}

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question, let alone providing an answer